# SSRS не отображает QR-код

Tags: c#, qrcode, ssrs

Генерирую QR-код на C# с помощью Qr Code Library:

```
QRCodeEncoder qrEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
Image img = qrEncoder.Encode( inputValue == null ? "" : inputValue );

using ( var stream = new MemoryStream() )
{
    img.Save( stream, ImageFormat.Png );
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Код работает в цикле HttpListener, HttpListener получает запрос и отправляет ответ в виде массива байтов, сгенерированного приведенным выше кодом. Браузер отображает изображение QR-кода нормально, а вот заставить это делать SSRS не удается. В Report Bulider добавляю объект изображения, выставляю внешний источник и пишу в строке источника следующий код:

="http://192.168.1.4:8090/GenerateQrCode?inputValue=123456"

123456 - для тестов, планируется получать это значение из базы данных. Но вместо QR-кода выводится красный крестик. При этом строка ="http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=123456" работает отлично. И SSRS, и генератор QR-кода работают на одном и том же сервере в локальной сети. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Что показывает превью репорта? Возможно, есть какие-то warnings?

Comment: Нет, вообще никаких ошибок. В превью на месте изображения красный крестик.